# Have Two iteration in Current Scrum TFS

Tags: tfs, iteration, scrum

I want to know is it possible to have two or more iteration in current section for scrum in TFS. 
for example for one team with different Date can I have 2 or more iteration . 
also can I add some new field to my Epic. For Example Name of my Customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each team has his/her own current iteration. But you need to switch to that specific team for the section to update.

There is no option for one team to show multiple iterations under current nor is it possible to show all iterations that are "current" for all teams.